# Is it possible to declare and use $1, $2, etc values in a Postgres INSERT?

Tags: postgresql

I have a ton of statements like:

```
INSERT INTO app.organization (name, org_type)
        VALUES ($1, $2)
```

in my code. I'd like to grab that, paste it into a SQL query window, declare $1 and $2 on the first two lines and then run the query. I haven't found an answer to this. It looks like it's not possible but I would like to confirm it directly instead of indirectly. It would be a lot faster than selecting the `$1` and pasting a new value in there.

Comment: What client program are you using?  "SQL query window" sounds GUI.

Comment: mix of pgAdmin 4 and Go Db package

Comment: I provided an answer but just wanted to comment on the client. I find that DBeaver is a far superior tool to pgAdmin. It's also has a free community edition that has plenty of functionality. Humble opinion just in case you want to check it out.

Comment: I tried it in the past. Worth another look, thanks.

Comment: @JSpratt you were right about DBeaver

Comment: @jcollum Haha, I'm glad you found it beneficial. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `PREPARED` statement, you can prepare a set of values and define it on execute.

From postgreSQL docs:

```
PREPARE fooplan (int, text, bool, numeric) AS
    INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);
EXECUTE fooplan(1, 'Hunter Valley', 't', 200.00);
```

Follow the [ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html):